# ipywidgets graph widget implementation

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Good day

I have been on this all day. I am trying to add widgets to my notebooks on my Jupyter(ipython) notebook. Below is my code which makes sense in my head but it is not populating anything. I am trying to control the list of values in StatusesList through a widget so it changes the graph populated. Please help.

```
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf
init_notebook_mode()
cf.go_offline()
import pandas as pd
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Complaints Management.xlsx")
df_status = df[['Status', 'Member Number']].groupby('Status').count()

StatusesList = df_status.index.tolist()

GragphValueList = df_status["Member Number"].tolist()
# w = Output()

def f(x):
    x = StatusesList
    return x
    interact(f, x = StatusesList)


    fig_status = {
    'data': [{'labels': x,
    'values': GragphValueList,
    'type': 'pie'}],
    'layout': {'title': 'Complaints by status'}
    }

    iplot(fig_status)
```

[file sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf82tipe5puedb0/Complaints%20Management.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you provider the excel file (or a sample file)?

Comment: Hi @nluigi please find sample with dummy data attached.

Comment: Currently you retrieve the number of complaints and their status and show which ones are open, closed or in progress and plot this in a pie-chart. What would you like to make interactive? what should happen?

Comment: @nluigi thanks for the reply and apologies for such a late response, it has been hectic at work.This solution you gave is useful, but i was thinking more of a filter that would affect the actual values to affect what the graph shows i.e 'Low', 'Medium' or 'High'. I know this reflects by default from the plotly graph below, but not on all graph types, it would also be useful for flexibility.

Comment: i don't understand, can you give an example?

Comment: @nluigi As in, i need to change the output display of the graph. Right now the 'Complaints by Priority' graph shows 3 outputs namely: 'Low', 'High' and 'Medium'. I want to e.g make it display only 'Low' and 'High' using a widget. I know plotly adds its own by default, but if i can control it with an ipywidget then that would give me more flexibility.

Comment: @nluigi i would get more flexibility by controlling more than one graph using one widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this type of interactivity right?

```
by_list = ['Priority', 'Status', 'Deadline', 'Query Category'] #df.keys().tolist()

@interact(x = by_list )
def f(x):
    df_data = df[[x, 'Member Number']].groupby(x).count()
    fig_status = {
    'data': [{'labels': df_data.index.tolist(),
    'values': df_data["Member Number"].tolist(),
    'type': 'pie'}],
    'layout': {'title': 'Complaints by %s' % x}
    }

    iplot(fig_status)
```

You have control over the `by_list` by adding or removing string corresponding to fields in your Excel. It is also possible to get all fields using `df.keys().tolist()` but this might be a little unstable.

PS. Thank you for showing me plotly, I hadn't heard/seen it before but it can produce some nice (interactive) statistical graphs!

[image]
[image]